# What type of properties should I use if it's supposed to store raw binary data

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I need to store/expose raw binary data (content of binary files) on my classes. What kind of type should I use?

Options I have considered so far:

1. `byte[]`

   This generates [warning CA1819](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0fss9skc.aspx):

   > Arrays returned by properties are not write-protected, even if the property is read-only. To keep the array tamper-proof, the property must return a copy of the array. Typically, users will not understand the adverse performance implications of calling such a property. Specifically, they might use the property as an indexed property.
2. `MemoryStream`

   `MemoryStream` is `IDisposable` so the owner would be responsible of disposing it, but reference to the `MemoryStream` might outlive the owner. An option would be simply not disposing the stream since it does not require it.
   A `MemoryStream` is also not thread-safe and care should be taken about stream position. Of course consumers may use `GetBuffer` but that is not much safer than option 1.

UPDATE

3. `ReadOnlyList<byte>`

   I am concerned of performance. This binary data often needs to be passed into external code using `byte[]`, getting that `byte[]` from a `ReadOnlyList<byte>` have performance impact.

Comment: How about having an `IReadOnlyList<byte>` as the type of your property?

Comment: There is also `BitArray` type in C#.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri updated question

Comment: Thinking more about this considering that performance is important and that data is consumed as byte[] I start to think the best way would be to use byte[] and override the warning and leave with the unlikely risk that the array is modified by consumers

Comment: [`ReadOnlySpan<byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=netstandard-2.1)?